# Is there any integral for the Golden Ratio?

Tags: calculus, integration, big-list, golden-ratio

I was wondering about important/famous mathematical constants, like $e$, $\pi$, $\gamma$, and obviously the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $\phi$.
The first three ones are really well known, and there are lots of integrals and series whose results are simply those constants. For example:

$$ \pi = 2 e \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1}\ \text{d}x$$

$$ e = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$$

$$ \gamma = -\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x\ e^{x - e^{x}}\ \text{d}x$$

Is there an interesting integral<sup>*</sup> (or some series) whose result is simply $\phi$?

* *Interesting integral* means that things like

$$\int\limits_0^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x}{\phi}}\ \text{d}x$$

are not a good answer to my question.

Comment: You can skim [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html), on WolframAlpha; e.g. Eq (12) and (13).

Comment: Related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921293/golden-ratio-from-new-formula-perhaps-from-theory-of-modular-units) introducing an infinite product for GR. And [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221584/how-many-infinite-series-representations-of-the-golden-ratio-are-in-existence)

Comment: Also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/563063/11619). Somewhat famous locally :-)

Comment: In principle, any infinite sum can be expressed as an appropriate contour integral; thus, any of the known infinite sums for $\phi$ can be expressed as contour integrals.

Comment: Hey guys could we get done proofs of these integrals please?

Comment: An interesting place where the golden ratio comes out is in the calculation of the order of convergence of the secant method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you for that. good god, that answer was a self contained symphony!

Comment: We have the following series representation: $$\phi=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1331}{250} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n+1)!}{5^{3n+1}(n!)^2}.$$

Comment: If $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ then $$\int_0^1\frac 1{\sqrt x(1+x)}\,\mathrm dx=\int_{\frac{\varphi^{3/2}-2}{\varphi^{3/2}+2}}^\varphi\frac 1{\sqrt x(1+x)}\,\mathrm dx=\frac \pi{2}$$ This is just $\arctan$ manipulation, but I guess it fits here lol

Comment: $\int_0^{\operatorname{arccot} 2}\frac{x}{2\cos 2x + \sin 2x}dx = \frac{\operatorname{arccot} 2}{2 \sqrt{5}} \ln \phi$

Comment: [$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{125}{12}\sqrt[10]{\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}} (x^2 - x) \, dx = \color{red}{\phi}\color{blue}{\pi}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888844/showing-int-11-frac12512-sqrt10-frac1-x1-x-x2-x)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For $k>0$, we have

[$$\bbox[8pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large \int_0^\infty  \ln \left( \frac{x^2-2kx+k^2}{x^2+2kx\cos \sqrt{\pi^2-\phi}+k^2}\right) \;\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}=\phi}}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1069376/146687)
I hope you find this integral interesting.

**Extra:**
$$\bbox[8pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large \int_0^\infty  \frac{x^{\frac\pi5-1}}{1+x^{2\pi}} \mathrm dx=\phi}}$$

Comment: Click the box for the proof

Comment: this one is awesome ()+1

Comment: I accepted your answer because you definitely wrote me what I wanted. Thank you so much for your beautiful elegant answer.

Comment: It was a bit deflating to realize that, more generally, $$\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^{\pi/k-1}}{1+x^{2\pi}}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}\csc\Big( \frac{\pi}{2k}\Big)$$ and the second result was just the case $k=5$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Everything is a special case of something.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I thought something was the special case of everything?

Answer (score 133):

Potentially interesting:

$$\log\varphi=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Perhaps also worthy of consideration:

$$\arctan \frac{1}{\varphi}=\frac{\int_0^2\frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx}{\int_0^2 dx}=\frac{\int_{-2}^2\frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx}{\int_{-2}^2 dx}$$

A development of the first integral:

$$\log\varphi=\frac{1}{2n-1}\int_0^{\frac{F_{2n}+F_{2n-2}}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

$$\log\varphi=\frac{1}{2n}\int_1^{\frac{F_{2n+1}+F_{2n-1}}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

which stem from the relationship $(x-\varphi^m)(x-\bar\varphi^m)=x^2-(F_{m-1}+F_{m+1})x+(-1)^m$, where $\bar\varphi=\frac{-1}{\varphi}=1-\varphi$ and $F_k$ is the $k$th Fibonacci number. I particularly enjoy:

$$\log\varphi=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$\log\varphi=\frac{1}{6}\int_1^{9}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
$$\log\varphi=\frac{1}{9}\int_0^{38}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$\log\varphi=\frac{1}{12}\int_1^{161}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Comment: Wow. Did you come up with this by yourself ?

Comment: @user230452 Unfortunately not! Stems from the fact that $\text{arcsinh}{\frac{1}{2}}=\log\varphi$, and this connection comes by noting that $x^2-x-1=0\implies \frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: This is somehow really really beautiful! Esthetically speaking :D Thank you for that interesting result!

Comment: What about $$\int_0^{1/2}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+3\right)\,dx$$

Comment: +1 for the understatement, the neat answer and the awesome username. I assume you greet other $\pi r8$s by saying "$Ar^k$" for some $k\geq2$.

Comment: @KimPeek Glad you like it (them)!

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is nice, though I am generally partial to cases where the integrand is all together in one piece

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed - though I'm humbled enough by the reception this first integral seems to have received that I might be well-advised to go by $\varphi$r$8$ from here onwards ^^.

Comment: @πr8: would you prefer $\frac{x+3\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Somewhat - basically, the less the function looks like a sum/composition of atypical functions, the more attractive I generally find it. If I were looking to develop your suggestion, I'd personally lean towards $\frac{2}{\varphi}=\int_0^2\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\, dx$. Mostly a matter of taste though.

Answer (score 89):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029631), it is shown that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+2x+5}\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi{2\sqrt\phi}
$$

Comment: Awesome!! A strict link between $\pi$ and $\phi$, I love those things. Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant!! Absolutely amazing

Comment: wow! this is incredible

Comment: So we know $\pi=2e\int_0^{\infty}{\cos(x)\over x^2+1}\text{d}x$ and $e=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over k!}$ from the OP, then this answer says $\int_0^\infty{\sqrt{x}\over x^2+2x+5}\text{d}x={\pi\over 2\sqrt{\Phi}}$. My immediate thought was to combine the above to get $\Phi=\left({\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over k!}\int_0^{\infty}{\cos(x)\over x^2+1}\text{d}x \over \int_0^\infty{\sqrt{x}\over x^2+2x+5}\text{d}x}\right)^2$, which might be considered "interesting".

Comment: So very nice  ! Somehow you perhaps can rope in $e$ too.

Answer (score 60):

An identity derived from the [Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction) ($R(q)$, not defined here) exhibits a $\phi$ factor:

$$ \frac{1}{(\sqrt{\phi\sqrt{5}})e^{2\pi/5}} = 1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-8\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-10\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-12\pi}}{\cdots}}}}}}$$

[image: artist view of the identity]

and one can then obtain a formula like:
$$ \ln \left( \sqrt{4\phi+3}-\phi^2\right) = -\frac{1}{5}\int_{e^{-2\pi}}^1 \frac{(1-t)^5(1-t^2)^5(1-t^3)^5 \dots}{(1-t^5)(1-t^{10})(1-t^{15}) \dots}\frac{dt}{t}$$
which beautifully links integrals, $e$, $\phi$ and $\pi$. It is described for instance in [Golden Ratio and a Ramanujan-Type Integral](http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/axioms2010058).
Not very practical though to obtain $\phi$ rational approximations.

In M. D. Hirschhorn, [A connection between $\pi$ and $\phi$](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Emikeh/webpapers/paper197.pdf), Fibonacci Quarterly, 2015, another asymptotic relation is:

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}=\lim_{n\to \infty} 2n {5}^{1/4}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{n+k}{k}/\phi^{5n+5/2}$$

Comment: The genius of Ramanujan will always remain a mystery.. what a genius.

Comment: And I believe it is a good thing that this remains a mystery.

Comment: mind... blown...

Comment: @FourierTransform right!

Comment: The link seems dead, here is an archived version: [pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20150922074159if_/https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/2/1/58/pdf), [html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180131025715if_/https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/2/1/58/htm).

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov I even made a question on this ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2655006/the-most-complex-formula-for-the-golden-ratio-varphi-that-i-have-ever-seen-h)) :D

Comment: Btw, here is another formula owing to Ramanujan: $$1-\frac {(1!)^2}{2!\times 3^2}+\frac{(2!)^2}{4!\times 5^2}-\frac{(3!)^2}{6!\times 7^2}+\frac{(4!)^2}{8!\times 9^2}-\cdots$$ $$=\frac{\pi^2}6-3\ln^2\varphi$$

Answer (score 46):

$$\int_{-1}^1 dx \frac1x \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \log{\left (\frac{2 x^2+2 x+1}{2 x^2-2 x+1}\right )}  = 4 \pi \operatorname{arccot}{\sqrt{\phi}}$$

Comment: There is a sign error in the log term

Comment: @LaplacianFourier: Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, isn't this like the most upvoted post on this site? Always fun reading even though I don't know enough math do do it..

Comment: @FarazMasroor: Actually, I think the 7th or 8th-most upvoted post.  But thanks - if you want to learn feel free to ask questions!

Comment: ...might as well include a link: [**MSE 562964**](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/562694)

Comment: I hate to say it @FarazMasroor , but the most upvoted post is...

Comment: one letter long

Answer (score 35):

Here's a series:

$$
\phi = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{F_nF_{n-1}}
$$

where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

To see this, rewrite the numerator using the identity $(-1)^n=F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_n^2$, at which point the summand becomes
$$
\frac{F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_n^2}{F_nF_{n-1}}=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}
$$
and so the sum telescopes: the partial sum ending at $n$ is equal to
$$
\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\frac{F_2}{F_1}=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} - 1
$$
which gives the original expression for the series via the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = \phi$.

Comment: Was this the first definition of golden ratio or did it have a definition before that ?

Comment: @user230452 $\phi = \frac { 1+ \sqrt 5}2$

Comment: I mean, didn't that number come from the Fibonacci series itself or did it already have a definition and was found again in the Fibonacci series ?

Comment: @user230452 The golden ratio first arose as a ratio between quantities $a,b$ for which ratio $a:b$ is the same as ratio $a+b:a$. Hence, it came before (or at least independently of) Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @Wojowu I agree that the original definition is independent of the Fibonacci sequence, though we're really using "independent" in the sense of copyright law rather than anything else. Fundamentally, it's essentially the same definition.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, all definitions of golden ratio are essentially the same definition by that line of thought, because they define the same number.

Comment: @Wojowu My point was just that the Fibonacci sequence is all about situations where you're dealing with $a$, $b$ and $a+b$, and so is the classical definition of the golden ratio. Whereas, for example, $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is a completely different way of defining the same number.  Anyway, I'm just nit-picking.

Comment: @user230452 the Greeks were very keen on the Golden Ratio. I had always assumed from his name that Fibonacci was much later. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio confirms this.

Answer (score 32):

Based on the fact that $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$:

> $$\varphi = \int_4^5 \frac32+\frac1{4\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d}x$$

Based on the fact that $\varphi = 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{5})$:

> $$\varphi = \int_{\tfrac{\pi}{5}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} 2\sin(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I wanted to do that at first, but thought it wasn't 'interesting' by OP's standards

Comment: @YuriyS I just took 'not interesting' as 'directly containing $\varphi$, or a trivial variation on it'

Comment: Awesome, the second one is great!!

Answer (score 31):

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1+x^{10}} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{5 \phi}.$$

Comment: Great! Another integral that relates two constants! Thank you!

Comment: @KimPeek, there is an infinite number of integrals of this kind

Comment: @YuriyS The more I see, the happier I am :D

Comment: Although it adds nothing, I think having $5x^2$ on the left instead of $5$ at the denominator on the right looks even prettier (if possible)

Answer (score 26):

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x^\phi)^\phi}=1$$

Comment: Astounding beauty

Comment: Another integral involving $\phi$ that might be surprising at first sight :) $$\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^2}\frac1{1+x^\phi}dx=\frac\pi4.$$

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov How would you solve both of your integrals one? My mind's blank, and I'm not able to simplify them adequately. :/

Comment: $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^\phi)^\phi}=x \, (1+x^\phi)^{1-\phi}\color{gray}{+C}$, that can be checked by differentiation. The second one is really easy. Hint: if you replace $\phi$ with $\phi^2$, it will still have the same value.

Answer (score 22):

All the following is based on the simple fact that:

$$\phi=2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{5} \right)=2 \sin \left( \frac{3\pi}{10} \right)$$

These integrals are the small sample of what we can build using this identity:

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x)x^{0.7}}=\phi-1$$

$$\frac{1}{1.4 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2x^{0.7}}=\phi-1$$

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{1} \frac{dx}{(1-x)^{0.3}x^{0.7} }=\phi-1$$

$$\frac{5}{3 \pi} \int_0^{1} \frac{x^{0.3}dx}{(1-x)^{0.3} }=\phi-1$$

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{0.3}x }=\phi-1$$

$$\frac{1}{0.21 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{0.3}dx}{(1+x)^{3} }=\phi-1$$

Take any tables of definite integrals, find any one that ends in a trig function and set the parameters to obtain $\phi$.

---

You can find the following infinite product for $\phi$ [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/monthly_augsep12_page645.pdf)

$$2 \phi=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{100k(k+1)+5^2}{100k(k+1)+3^2}$$

It's converging slowly, see the link for the proof using the properties of Gamma function.

By numerical computation at $50000$ terms this infinite product gives only $5$ correct digits for $\phi$, giving $1.618029$ instead of $1.618034$.

Using the infinite product for $\cos(x)$, we get:

$$\frac{\phi}{2}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1- \frac{4}{5^2 (2k-1)^2} \right)$$

This infinite product at $50000$ terms gives $\phi=1.618035$, only $4$ correct digits. This is actually almost the same product, because if we rearrange it we get:

$$\frac{\phi}{2}=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{100 k (k+1)+21}{100 k (k+1)+25} \right)$$

I suggest looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921293/golden-ratio-from-new-formula-perhaps-from-theory-of-modular-units) for much more interesting product.

Answer (score 19):

How about this one:

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}}=\frac{2}{\phi}-\ln \phi$$

There is an infinitely nested radical in the denominator.

A finite one is also possible:

> $$\int_0^{1/16} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=\phi-2\ln (\phi)-\frac12$$

Comment: The first one is AMAZING!! Thank you for having shared it! :O

Comment: Might help in the second to note that $\ln(\phi+1)=2\ln\phi$

Comment: @TimeMaster The 1st integral is only a fancy representation of

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}\ dx$$

Comment: @SophieAgnesi, my secret is revealed! Curses!

Answer (score 18):

The length of the logarithmic spiral $\rho=e^{2\theta}$ up to $\theta=0$ is given by

$$\int_{-\infty}^0\sqrt{\rho^2+\dot\rho^2}d\theta=\int_{-\infty}^0\sqrt{1+2^2}e^{2\theta}d\theta=\phi-\frac12.$$

Comment: Nice. Can you re-adjust the spiral so that length is $\phi $  exactly ?

Comment: @Narasimham: I don't see an immediate way to achieve that.

Comment: You already have $\sqrt{5}$ under your integral. Good example though

Answer (score 12):

I am not taking credit for this. I am just posting this because it answers the question. I give Felix Marin and Olivier Oloa complete credit for these results.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(1+4\sin^2 x)\text{ d}x=\pi\log\left(\varphi\right)$$

and

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(1+4\sin^4 x)\text{ d}x=\pi\log \frac{\varphi+\sqrt{\varphi}}{2}$$

Again, not mine. But they definitely deserve to be here

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for having posted them here. The first one is so beautiful!!

Answer (score 12):

**Five:Pi:Phi**

Coincidence closed form

$$\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\mathrm dx \sqrt[5]{\tan(x)}\cdot{\ln(\csc^2(x))\over \sin(2x)}=\color{blue}5\color{red}\pi\color{brown}\phi$$

Answer (score 10):

$$\int_0^\infty x(2x-1)\,\delta(x^2-x-1)\,dx$$

---

**Update**:

As pointed by Yuriy, we must take into account the derivative of the argument of the $\delta$ function. This is why the corrective factor $2x-1$ appears.

More generally,

$$\int_I x|g'(x)|\delta(g(x))\,dx$$ evaluates to the root of $g$ contained in the interval $I$, provided there is only one. The first factor $x$ can be replaced by any function $f(x)$ to yield the value of that function at the root.

Comment: Beautiful!! Dirac Delta. Very easy and elegant, thank you!

Comment: A great idea, actually! We can do it for any algebraic number, it seems

Comment: @YuriyS: yep, provided you isolate the desired root in an interval.

Comment: Actually, Wolframalpha gives another value for this integral: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x+DiracDelta%5Bx%5E2-x-1%5D+from+x%3D0+to+infinity

Comment: In general $\delta [g(x)]=\sum_k \frac{\delta (x-x_k)}{| g'(x_k)|}$

Comment: @YuriyS: quite right, I forgot that. Fortunately, we can fix by multiplying by $|g'(x)|$.

Comment: @YuriyS: the method extends to all transcendental numbers that can be expressed as a root of a function, such as $\pi$ or $e$ or $W(2)$...

Answer (score 10):

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^{10}}dx=\frac{\phi\pi}{5}
$$

Comment: Awesome one!!!!

Answer (score 10):

**An integral uniting some favourite mathematical constants**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2}{(\phi^n t)^2+(F_{2n+1}-\phi F_{2n})(\pi t^2+\zeta(3)t-e^{\gamma})^2}\mathrm dt=1$$

Where,

[$\phi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio); Golden ratio

[$\zeta(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant); Apery's constant

[$\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant); Euler-Mascheroni's constant

[$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)); Euler Number

[$F_{n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number); Fibonacci number

and $\pi=3.14...$

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a collection of the series with reciprocal binomial coefficients.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=\frac{4}{5} \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} \ln \phi \right)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=-\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} \ln \phi$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=-2 \ln^2 \phi$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5} \ln \phi$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=\frac{8\sqrt{5}}{5} \ln \phi-4 \ln^2 \phi$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{5} \ln \phi-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)^2}  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=1-\sqrt{5} \ln \phi+ \ln^2 \phi$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2(n^2-1)}  \left( \begin{matrix} 2n  \\ n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=4\ln^2 \phi-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \ln \phi-\frac{3}{8}$$

A one with $\pi$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \begin{matrix} 4n  \\ 2n \end{matrix} \right)^{-1}=\frac{16}{15}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{27} \pi-\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{25} \ln \phi $$

Source [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

Here is another one

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos (2x^2)\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\phi \pi\over 5}$$

Comment: Very cool one!!

Answer (score 7):

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1+x^8}{1+x^{10}}dx=\frac{\pi}{\phi^5-8}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Consider the sequence

$1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,...$

where $a_1=1,a_{n+1}\in\{a_n,a_n+1\}$, and $a_n$ is the number of times $n$ occurs in the sequence.  Then if we assume that $a_n$ grows asymptotically as $\alpha n^\beta$, we get

$\alpha=\phi^{1/{\phi^2}}$

$\beta=1/\phi$.

I saw this is a textbook problem on asymptotic analysis.  It turns out that for all $n$ the asymptotic expression is well within one unit of the actual $a_n$.

Comment: I give up!  How do I put braces around an explicitly written set!?!

Comment: Use \{ and \} instead of the normal braces.

Answer (score 6):

We can prove the inequalities

$$\frac{3}{2}<\frac{8}{5}<\phi<\frac{13}{8}<\frac{5}{3}$$

with representations

$$\begin{align}\phi&=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4+x}}\\
\\
\phi&=\frac{8}{5}+\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{121+4x}}\\
\\
\phi&=\frac{13}{8}-\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{80+x}}\\
\\
\phi&=\frac{5}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{45+4x}}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x-x^2)}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x-x^2)}xdx=2\ln^2\varphi$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-3x+x^2)\ln x}{x}dx=\frac85 \zeta (3)+\frac{2}{5} \pi ^2 \ln \varphi-2 i \pi  \ln^2\varphi$$

Comment: Could those people vote to delete please explain the reason?

Comment: Maybe they are just ignorant.

Answer (score 5):

So you said that series are OK, so I will offer a few:

$$\phi=\frac{13}{8}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)!4^{(2n+3)}}$$

$$\phi=2\cos (\pi/5)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{((-1)^k (\pi/5)^{2 k}}{(2k)!}$$

$$\phi=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4^{-n}\binom{1/2}{n}$$

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly a series, but might also be of interest:

$$1-\frac{1}{\phi}=\frac{1}{\phi^2}=\frac{1}{5} \left(1+\frac{1}{5} \left(1+\frac{1}{5} \left(1+\frac{1}{5} \left(1+\dots \right)^2  \right)^2  \right)^2 \right)^2$$

---

$$\frac{1}{\phi^4}=\frac{1}{5} \left(1-\frac{1}{5} \left(1-\frac{1}{5} \left(1-\frac{1}{5} \left(1-\dots \right)^2  \right)^2  \right)^2 \right)^2$$

$$\frac{1}{\phi^4}=\frac{1}{9} \left(1+\frac{1}{9} \left(1+\frac{1}{9} \left(1+\frac{1}{9} \left(1+\dots \right)^2  \right)^2  \right)^2 \right)^2$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $ F_0=0, F_1=1 ; F_{n+1}=F_{n-1}+F_n
$ be the Fibonacci numbers

$\zeta(s)$  is the zeta function. Then:

$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(-1)^{n+1}\phi F_n+(-1)^nF_{n+1}\right]^{n^{-(s+1)}}=\phi^{-\zeta(s)}
$$

Comment: This is Brilliant!!!

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x+x^2)^2+x^2}=\pi\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\phi}{5}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Double integral of $\phi$
$$-\frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm dx \mathrm dy}{\left(\frac{1}{5}-x+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-y+\frac{y^2}{5}}}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\phi^4}\right)\ln\left(\frac{\phi^2+1}{\phi^4}\right)$$

Without the natural logarithm
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{(2x^2-2x+1)^2\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\sqrt{(\phi+y^2)^3}}\mathrm dx \mathrm dy=-\frac{1}{\phi^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

By Euler's reflection formula, it follows that

$$
\int_0^\infty{x^{s-1}\over1+x}\mathrm dx={\pi s\over\sin(\pi s)}\tag1
$$

Accordingly, we can find an $s$ such that $\sin(\pi s)$ can be associated with $\phi$. As it turns out, we do have some special angle that allows us to do so.

[image]

By observing the geometric properties of this triangle, we can deduce the following relationship

$$
\triangle ABC\sim\triangle BDA\cong\triangle DBA
$$

which implies

$$
{BC\over AB}={AB\over BD}
$$

Now, due to the properties of isosceles triangles, we get

$$
AB=AD=CD\Rightarrow BC=BD+CD=BD+AB
$$

Thus, we obtain

$$
1+{BD\over AB}={AB\over BD}
$$

To convenience the derivation, set $AB=1,BD=y$ so that the above identity becomes

$$
1+y=\frac1y\Rightarrow y^2+y-1=0\Rightarrow y={-1+\sqrt5\over2}=\frac1\phi
$$

Again, by the properties of isosceles, we deduce

$$
CE={1+y\over2}
$$

As a result, we obtain $\cos36^\circ$ from its definition:

$$
\cos36^\circ={CE\over CD}={CE\over AB}={1+y\over2}={1+\sqrt5\over4}=\frac\phi2
$$

Now, due to the conversion that

$$
90^\circ-36^\circ=54^\circ={3\pi\over10}
$$

we obtain

$$
\sin\left(3\pi\over10\right)=\frac\phi2
$$

Therefore, setting $s=3/10$ in (1), we obtain

$$
\fbox{$\Large\int_0^\infty{x^{-7/10}\over1+x}\mathrm dx={2\pi\over\phi}$}
$$

Answer (score 3):

-I remember really liking this one:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\text{dx dy}}{\varphi^6-x^2y^2}=\frac{\pi^2-18\log^2\varphi}{24\varphi^3}$$

I most liked it because it was specific to $\varphi$

-Also, we can note [this M.SE result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325/evaluate-int-01-frac-log-left-1x2-sqrt3-right1x-mathrm-dx) (with some interpolation)

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1+x^{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}})}{1+x}\text{dx}=$$$$\frac{\pi^2}{12}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}\right)+\log(\varphi)\log(2)\log(\sqrt{\alpha+1}+\sqrt{\alpha-1})\log(\text{something})$$

Perhaps someone can help me fill in $\text{"something"}$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another one
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{5^{\frac{x}{4}}+5^{\frac{1}{2}}-5^0}dx=\phi
$$

Answer (score 3):

This one is a bit messy.

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(\sqrt5^x)^{2^{-(\sqrt5-1)}}+\sqrt5-1}dx=2^{\phi^{-3}}\cdot\phi
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^{\frac{10}{3}}}dx=\frac{3\pi}{5\phi}$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $\frac{2}{1+\sqrt5}=\frac{1}{\phi}$

$$\int_0^1\frac{2}{(1+\sqrt5x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{\phi}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_0^1  \frac{200\sqrt5(1-x^2)-300(1-x)^2}{ \left[5\sqrt5(1+x)^2-15(1-x^2)+2\sqrt5(1-x)^2  \right]^2}dx=(2\phi+1)(\phi+2)$$

Answer (score 3):

> $$\int_{0}^{\phi}(1-x+x^2)^{1/\phi}(1-\phi^2x+\phi^3x^2)\mathrm dx=2^{\phi}\cdot\phi$$

A bit over-crowed in term of $\phi$

Answer (score 2):

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{\left(1+\phi  x^2\right) \sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx=\frac{\pi }{\phi }$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one:

$$\int_{0}^{1}(2x-1)\left(\frac{1}{x(1-x)}+\frac{\phi\pi}{(1+x)(2-x)}+\frac{\phi \pi^2}{(2+x)(3-x)}+\frac{\phi \pi^3}{(2+x)(3-x)}+\cdots\right)-\frac{1}{\ln(1-x)}+\frac{x^{e-1}}{\ln x} \mathrm dx=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$\textrm{ Let }y=\frac{1}{1+x^{2 \pi}}, \textrm{ then }x=\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{2 \pi}} \textrm{ and }d x=-\frac{1}{2 \pi}(1-y)^{\frac{1}{2 \pi}-1} y^{-\frac{1}{2 \pi}-1} d y.$

Putting back changes the integral to a Beta function

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{\pi-5}{5}}}{1+x^{2 \pi}} d x &=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^1 y^{-\frac{1}{10}}(1-y)^{-\frac{9}{10}} d y \\ &=\frac{1}{2 \pi} B\left(\frac{9}{10}, \frac{1}{10}\right) \end{aligned} \tag*{} $

Using the reflection property of Beta function: $B(x, 1-x)=\pi \csc(\pi x) \textrm{  for all } x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ yields

$\displaystyle \boxed{ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{\pi-5}{5}}}{1+x^{2 \pi}} d x =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \pi \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right) =\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=\phi} \tag*{} $

Answer (score 1):

> $$\int_{0}^{1}{1-x^{\phi}\over 1-x}+{x(1-\phi x^{1\over \phi}+{1\over \phi}x^{\phi})\over (1-x)^2}\mathrm dx=\phi$$

Answer (score 1):

Connecting three well-known constants together:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{\phi+\frac{1}{\phi}}\right)\cdot \frac{\mathrm dx}{4x^4+5x^2}=\frac{\pi}{e}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\phi+\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm dx \ln(x)\ln\left[\frac{x^\phi(-\ln(x))^{\phi^3}}{[1-\ln(x)]^{\phi^2}}\right]=\gamma \phi^3+\phi$$

$\gamma=0.57721...;Euler -constant$

$\phi=1.618...; Golden-ratio$

Comment: I like how you began with $\text{d}x$ lol

Answer (score 1):

$\gamma=0.57721...$; Euler constant

$\phi$; golden ratio

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1-xy}\cdot\frac{\ln\left(xy^{1/\phi}\right)}{\ln(xy)}\mathrm dxdy=1-\frac{\gamma}{\phi^2}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1-xy}\cdot\frac{\ln\left(xy^{\phi}\right)}{\ln(xy)}\mathrm 
dxdy=1+\frac{\gamma}{\phi}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1-xy}\cdot\frac{\ln\left(xy^{\phi^2}\right)}{\ln(xy)}\mathrm dxdy=1+\phi\gamma$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+4\sin^2x}=\frac{2\pi\phi}{\phi+2}\;\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;\;\phi=\frac{4\pi}{2\pi-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+4\sin^2x}}-2$$

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is my attempt to find another integral representation for Golden ratio using some special function as shown in the above image !!!!!!!

Comment: I already saw it in a past question of yours. It's really cool, can you prove it?

Comment: Can we see all the proof please ?

Comment: Does the constant $t$ have any significance other than this? Otherwise, not all that interesting (sorry), since you're just defining $t$ as $t=I^{-1}(\phi)$ and then concluding $I(t) = \phi$.

Comment: e.g. there also exists a constant at $x\approx 2.7573$ such that $\Gamma(x) = \phi$, but this isn't interesting since $\Gamma$ takes on all values in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Try typing this in Mathjax please