# Nontrivial integral representations for $e$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

There are a lot of integral representations for $\pi$ as well as infinite series, limits, etc. For other transcendental constants as well (like $\gamma$ or $\zeta(3)$).

However, for every definite integral that is equal to $e$ I can think of, the integrated function contains the exponent in some way.

> Can you provide some definite integrals that have $e$ as their value (or some elementary function of $e$ that is not a logarithm), without $e$ appearing in any way under the integral or as one of its limits (and without the limits for $e$, or the infinite series for $e$)?

The example or what I want is the following integral for $\pi$:

$$\int_0^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Note that your example is just the area under a quarter of a circle!

Comment: I assume that hyperbolic functions or trigonometric functions should not be an example?

Comment: Based on Quadarture rules, Brothers and Knox '98 gave several non-trivial representations for $e$. See http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/jmr/article/viewFile/3724/3320

Comment: Possibly Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653979/is-there-any-integral-for-the-golden-ratio(I'm not suggesting this question is a duplicate-just saying the two questions seem similar.

Comment: @Travis, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, hyperbolic functions are out. Limits as well (except for $\infty$ as the integral limit). Bacon, I see only limits in the paper you offered

Comment: $e=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1.2.3...(x-3)(x-2)(x-1) \int_{t}^{\sqrt{2x+t^{2}}} p ~ dp}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are asking whether *e* is a [period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods), the question remains, technically, still open, but its answer is not expected to be affirmative. As to the non-algebraic integrands, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{1+x^2}~dx~=~\frac\pi{e^{|a|}}$$

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about this kind of integrals, since they are usually evaluated by using the complex exponential