# Values of $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{dt}{1+t^n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

May be this question has already been asked here. I’m looking for differents methods for handling this integral.

Edit: I am looking for a closed form. Any suggestion or method is welcome.
Initially I wanted to find a closed form of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{ns+1}}$$
which leads me to this integral.

Comment: Do you know dominated convergence?  Please don't ask PSQ here.

Comment: Yes I know that

Comment: See section 6.3 of [Zorich, I](https://books.google.com/books?id=qA5FTMT7HE4C&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/777541/13130) and the references given there, some of which I feel sure address the specific definite integral you're asking about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conjecture for the value of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^{p}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031009/conjecture-for-the-value-of-int-01-frac11xpdx) See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592898/what-do-we-know-about-sum-limitsn-0-infty-frac-1nkn1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation used in this answer:**

$\ln(x)$ is the real-valued natural logarithm. It admits values $x\in (0,\infty)$

$\log(x)=\ln|x|+i\arg(x)$ is the complex-valued natural logarithm, which admits values $x\in\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$

And $\arg(x)$ is the [complex argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) of $x$.

---

**Answer:**
Note that $1+x^n$ may be factored as 
$$1+x^n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-\lambda_{n,k})$$
Where $$\lambda_{n,k}=\exp\left[\frac{i\pi}n(2k+1)\right]$$
Hence 
$$H(x)=\frac1{1+x^n}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{x-\lambda_{n,k}}$$
Since we have now factored $H(x)$, we may do partial fractions, i.e. we may write

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{x-\lambda_{n,k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma_{n,k}}{x-\lambda_{n,k}}$$
for some coefficients $\Gamma_{n,k}$. We find $\Gamma_{n,k}$ by multiplying both sides by $\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(x-\lambda_{n,j})$ to get 
$$1=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\Gamma_{n,k}\prod_{j=0\\ j\neq k}^{n-1}(x-\lambda_{n,j})\right]$$
so for any $r\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ we plug in $x=\lambda_{n,r}$. The LHS stays the same, and every term on the RHS vanishes except for the term with $k=r$. Hence 
$$1=\Gamma_{n,r}\prod_{j=0\\ j\neq r}^{n-1}(\lambda_{n,r}-\lambda_{n,j})$$
$$\Rightarrow \Gamma_{n,r}=\prod_{j=0\\ j\neq r}^{n-1}\frac1{\lambda_{n,r}-\lambda_{n,j}}$$
See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3146813/583016) for a proof that 
$$\Gamma_{n,k}=-\frac{\lambda_{n,k}}{n}$$
Hence we have 
$$\frac1{1+x^n}=-\frac1n\sum_{k=0}\frac{\lambda_{n,k}}{x-\lambda_{n,k}}$$
Anyway, we may now integrate with our summation formula:
$$
\begin{align}
I_n&=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^n}\\
&=-\frac1n\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\lambda_{n,k}dx}{x-\lambda_{n,k}}\\
&=-\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\lambda_{n,k}j_{n,k}\\
\end{align}$$
Where
$$j_{n,k}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x-\lambda_{n,k}}=\ln\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n}+i\arg(1-\lambda_{n,k})-\frac{i\pi}{n}(2k+n+1)$$
Which I can prove to you in full detail if you'd like.

---

**The evaluation of $j_{n,k}$:**

We have that $$\frac{d}{dz}\log z=\frac1z$$
So we immediately have that 
$$j_{n,k}=\log(1-\lambda_{n,k})-\log(-\lambda_{n,k})$$
Then from $\log(x)=\ln|x|+i\arg x$ we have that 
$$j_{n,k}=\ln|1-\lambda_{n,k}|+i\arg(1-\lambda_{n,k})-\ln|-\lambda_{n,k}|-i\arg(-\lambda_{n,k})$$
From Euler's formula we have $\lambda_{n,k}=\cos\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n+i\sin\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n$, so 
$$|-\lambda_{n,k}|=|\lambda_{n,k}|=\sqrt{\cos^2\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n+\sin^2\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n}=1$$ 
Thus $\ln|-\lambda_{n,k}|=\ln1=0$, giving
$$j_{n,k}=\ln|1-\lambda_{n,k}|+i\arg(1-\lambda_{n,k})-i\arg(-\lambda_{n,k})$$
And since $\arg(xy)=\arg(x)+\arg(y)$ we have that 
$$\arg(-\lambda_{n,k})=\arg(-1)+\arg(\lambda_{n,k})=\pi+\frac\pi{n}(2k+1)=\frac{\pi}{n}(2k+n+1)$$
Then we see that 
$$\begin{align}
|1-\lambda_{n,k}|&=\sqrt{\left(1-\cos\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n\right)^2+\sin^2\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n}\\
&=\sqrt{1-2\cos\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n+\cos^2\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n+\sin^2\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n}\\
&=\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n}
\end{align}$$
So
$$j_{n,k}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x-\lambda_{n,k}}=\ln\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{\pi(2k+1)}n}+i\arg(1-\lambda_{n,k})-\frac{i\pi}{n}(2k+n+1)$$

Comment: Please provide that prove in detail

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE see my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot.$\quad$

Comment: you are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

With $t=\tan^{2/n}u,\,x=\sin^2 u$ your integral becomes $$\frac{2}{n}\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{2/n-1}udu=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{1/2}x^{1/n-1}(1-x)^{-1/n}dx=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{1}{2};\,\frac{1}{n},\,1-\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

If n is an integer greater than 1.

Your contour is a section of a circle with an angle of $e^{\frac {2\pi i}{n}}$

$\oint_\gamma f(t) \ dt =  \int_0^{\infty} f(t) \ dt + \lim_\limits{R\to\infty} \int_0^{\frac {2\pi}{n}} f(Re^{it}) iRe^{it} \ dt - \int_0^{\infty} f(e^{\frac {2\pi i}{n}} t)e^{\frac {2\pi i}{n}} \ dt$

$f(e^{\frac {2\pi i}{n}} t) = f(t)$

if $n > 1$

$\lim_\limits{R\to\infty} \int_0^{\frac {\pi}{n}} f(Re^{it}) iRe^{it} \ dt = 0$  (and does not converge otherwise)

$\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \ dt = \frac{1}{1-e^{\frac {2\pi i}{n}}}\oint_\gamma f(t) \ dt$

There is one pole inside the contour, and it evaluates to $-\frac{1}{n}e^{\frac{\pi i}{n}}$

$\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \ dt = \frac {\pi\csc \frac {\pi}{n}}{n}$