# Other integrals for the tribonacci constant?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, constants

The post, *[Is there an integral for the golden ratio?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653979/is-there-any-integral-for-the-golden-ratio)* gives numerous beautiful integrals for $\phi$. Some were just specializations of trigonometric evaluations such as,
$$F(k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\pi/k-1}}{1+x^{2\pi}}dx =\frac{1}{2}\csc\Big(\frac{\pi}{2k}\Big)=\phi,\quad\text{at}\;k=5$$
However, integrals for phi's cousin the ***tribonacci constant*** $T$ seem to be harder to find. Phi appears in the pentagon, dodecahedron, etc, but $T$ also has a geometric context, the snub cube,

$\hskip2.8in$ [image: Snub Cube]

One integral I know for $T$ is,
$$\beta\times \Bigl(\frac{T+1}{T}\Bigr)^2=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}dt = 1.570983\dots$$
where,
$$\beta=\frac{\Gamma\bigl(\tfrac{1}{11}\bigr)\, \Gamma\bigl(\tfrac{3}{11}\bigr)\, \Gamma\bigl(\tfrac{4}{11}\bigr)\, \Gamma\bigl(\tfrac{5}{11}\bigr)\, \Gamma\bigl(\tfrac{9}{11}\bigr)}{11^{1/4}(4\pi)^2}$$
$$k = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{\frac{2T+15}{2T+1}}}$$
though it is a bit unsatisfying as $T$ appears in the integrand.

> **Q:** Are there other nice integrals for the tribonacci constant $T$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A neat integral for the tribonacci constant $T$ involving the *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$ is:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \eta( i \, x)\,\eta(i \,11 x) \,dx = \frac{ \ln T}{\sqrt{11}} $$
There is also 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \eta( i x)\,\eta(i\, 23  x) \,dx = \frac{ \ln \rho}{\sqrt{23}} $$
where $\rho$ is the [plastic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html). Check [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031744/on-the-integral-int-0-infty-eta2i-x-dx-ln1-sqrt3-sqrt32-sqrt3) for more details, and more similar integrals.

Comment: Beautiful! A little experimentation showed that $$\int_0^{\infty} \eta( i x)\,\eta(i\, 5  x) \,dx = \frac{ \ln \big(\phi+\sqrt{\phi}\big)}{\sqrt{5}} $$ with the golden ratio $\phi$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yes, I have made a list of all the polynomials corresponding to these integrals (see my question for information): http://pastebin.com/y5GHTBEE

Answer (score 0):

Not an integral, but another relationship of interest: the tribonacci constant may be coupled in with trigonometric functions of hendecagonal angkes and this with the construction if the regular hendecagon. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258069/248217) gives more details on the summary given below.

The sines and tangents of hendecagonal angles may be related by various equalities such as

$4\sin(5\pi/11)-\tan(2\pi/11)=\sqrt{11}.$

The complete set of such equalities may be rendered into a symmetric form

$4\sin(3\theta)-\tan(\theta)=(k|11)\sqrt{11}$

where $\theta=2k\pi/11,(k|11)$ is the Legendre symbol of $k\bmod11$, and $k\in\mathbb Z$. But along with these multiples of $2\pi/11$ there is another value of $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$ for which the left side equals $+\sqrt{11}$, and that satisfies

$\color{blue}{2\cos\theta=T}.$

Thereby the tribonacci constant $T$ is coupled with the trigonometric values $2\cos(2k\pi/11)$, and as described in the referenced answer this coupling enters into a **neusis construction of the regular hendecagon.**