# Is there an integral for the Reciprocal Fibonacci constant?

Tags: integration, fibonacci-numbers

Inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653979/is-there-any-integral-for-the-golden-ratio), I thought I would ask a similar question. The Reciprocal Fibonacci constant $\psi$ is the value the infinite sum of the reciprocals of the Fibonacci numbers converge to, i.e:

$$\psi = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F_n}$$

Is there any known integral representation for $\psi$? Or just interesting integrals in general containing $\psi$?

*To clarify, integrals like

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x}{\psi}} dx = \psi$$ are NOT interesting integrals.