# Prove that $\int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\frac {\mathrm {d} z}{(\phi ^{n}z)^{2}+(F_{2n+1}-\phi F_{2n})(e^{\gamma }z^{2}+\zeta (3)z-\pi )^2}}=1$

Tags: improper-integrals, pi, golden-ratio, euler-mascheroni-constant

Recently while dealing with few interesting integrals, I was quite fascinated by this one:

$$\int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\dfrac {1}{(\phi ^{n}z)^{2}+(F_{2n+1}-\phi F_{2n})(e^{\gamma }z^{2}+\zeta (3)z-\pi )^2}}\,\mathrm {d} z=1$$

where $\phi$ represents the golden ratio, $\gamma$ represents the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number. I have no idea on how to prove this but a possible approach would be using residue theorem and complex analysis. I'm looking for a real analytic approach.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading $:)$

Comment: Out of personal interest: Where did you find this integral?

Comment: @vitamind Thanks for asking, I didn't find it on any website. I found it myself by constructing and generalizing some integrals involving golden ratio and zeta(3). Answer: By  **Hardworking**

Comment: Since the denominator is a real quartic, you can in principle factor it as a product of real quadratics and integrate the result using partial fractions. Actually doing so seems tedious....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you cannot use partial fractions later". skbmoore's answer does so.

Comment: @vitamind A very similar integral appears in this [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3106817/4781), but probably just a convergence of independent work.

Answer (score 11):

The proposed identity is a disguised version of
$$(*)\quad\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+(ax^2+bx-c)^2} = \frac{\pi}{c} \quad \text{with } a,b,c>0,$$
and a sketch proof will be given below.  It uses contour integration because that's the easiest thing I could think of.  It might be possible to prove the above ID with Glasser's theorem, or real integration, though you have to careful of the branch of the arctan function.

The important thing to notice is that the right-hand side is independent of $(a,b),$ once the positivity of those constants is assumed.

With $c=\pi,$ introduce a scaling parameter $\kappa$ and anequivalent expression is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+(\kappa (ax^2+bx-\pi))^2} = \frac{1}{\kappa}  $$
Let $\kappa=\phi^{-2n}$, $a=e^\gamma,$ $b=\zeta(3).$ Then
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+ \phi^{-4n} (e^\gamma x^2+\zeta(3)x-\pi)^2} = \phi^{2n}  $$
Division by $\phi^{2n}$ and the result is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(\phi^n x)^2+\phi^{-2n} (e^\gamma x^2+\zeta(3)x-\pi)^2} =1  $$

It is easy to show $F_{2n+1}-\phi F_{2n}=\phi^{-2n},$ so once (*) is proved, the OP's integral follows.

It is well-known that an integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$ in which the integrand has isolated poles can be computed with the residue theorem.  Factor the quartic polynomial; fortunately it is rater simple:
$$ (ax^2+bx-c)^2 + x^2 =a^2 (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4) \text{where} $$
$$ x_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2a}(i-b \pm \sqrt{(i-b)^2 + 4ac} )$$
$$ x_{3,4} = \frac{1}{2a}(-i-b \pm \sqrt{(-i-b)^2 + 4ac} )$$
For $a,b,c>0, \ \ x_{1,2}$ contribute poles in the upper half plane. Break factored integrand into partial fractions. You'll only keep the terms with $(x-x_1)$ and $(x-x_2).$ Therefore the integral is
$$I(a,b,c):=\quad\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+(ax^2+bx-c)^2} = $$
$$= \frac{2\pi i }{a^2}\Big(\frac{1}{(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)(x_2-x_4)}-
\frac{1}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_4)} \Big)$$
Substitute the $(a,b,c)$ dependent expression of the roots $x_{1,2}$ and simplify (I used Mathematica)  to get (*).

Comment: Very nice answer: approved!