Integrals for $\pi-\frac{333}{106}$ and $\frac{355}{113}-\pi$
Two integrals related to convergents of $\pi$ are given by
$$128\int_0^1 \frac{x^2(1-x)^2(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = 106\pi - 333 + \frac{1}{5}$$
$$64\int_0^1 \frac{x(1-x)^3(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = 355 - 113\pi + \frac{1}{5}$$
Are there similar expressions with positive integrands in small numbers that cancel the fractions $\frac{1}{5}$?

A short paper on some integrals showing $355/113>\pi$ can be found here.

Yes, I know, thanks. In that paper by Lucas larger numbers appear, which I believe could be lowered if another suitable form was found.

See also this earlier question for $333/106$ instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-an-integral-that-proves-pi-333-106

I think that plugging this factor (x-1/2) or something similar will lead to a simpler result. I bumped into 113 and 106 while looking for 22/7, actually.

Trying the root comes from this thread about the golden ratio, that leads to convergents very easily: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2315273/134791

How did you find these integrals?

I try symmetric structures on WolframAlpha. x^n(1-x)^m has zeros at 0 and 1 so I thought another zero just in the middle, at 1/2, could have a nice effect. The power has to be even not to break the positive integrand.

We may find some insight from the lower case $$16\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2(1-x)(x-\frac1{2})^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},\mathrm{d}x=-22+7\pi-\frac1{5}+\frac1{3}$$

And those examples directly comes from these 7th order approximations $$64\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2(1-x)^2(x^2-4x+1)^2}{(1+x^2)^6}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2} = -22+7\pi+\frac1{5}$$ $$256\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2(1-x)^4(x^2-4x+1)^2}{(1+x^2)^6}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2} = -333+106\pi+\frac1{5}$$ $$64\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x(1-x)^6(x^2-4x+1)^2}{(1+x^2)^6}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2} =355-113\pi+\frac1{5}$$

Unfortunately, the three simple linear combinations of summing two of them minus twice the other, to cancel the fraction, change the sign of the integrand in [0,1].

$\frac{22}{7}-\pi$ comes neat from a higher case:
$$\frac{4}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{x^3(x-\frac{1}{2})^2(1-x)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx =\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E1+%284%29%28x%29%5E3%28x-1%2F2%29%5E2%281-x%29%5E2%2F3%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E2%29

@Nanayajetzuki In my humble opinion, prior to (or in parallel with) the continuation of the investigation "whether there are similar expressions with positive integrands in small numbers that cancel the fractions 1/5?", may be it is worth to continue investigation whether there exist additional Pi convergents related equations, containing 1/5 fraction, and whether such equations could be generalized.

The unwanted fraction can also multiply $\pi$, such as in
$$3\int_0^1 \frac{x^5(x-\frac{1}{2})^2(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \frac{22}{7}-(1-\frac{1}{256})\pi$$
